# UITextLabel editing causing error when segueing

Tags: ios, uilabel, uialertview

I have a view controller with a `UITableView` and each table view cell has a `UILabel`.  Whenever a label is edited, I call a method within my `NSFileManager` controller that edits the name of the file associated with the text label.  If I tap a text label but never edit the name and tap return, the file manager controller will return an error and a `UIAlertView` saying the "file name already exists" will be shown in my view controller - which is fine.  However, if I tap a label to begin editing, but tap another button that segues to another view controller, the app will segue to the chosen view controller, the alert view will be shown, then the app will crash once I tap "Ok" button in the alert view.  Any idea how to fix this?

I implemented the `endEditing` method which resolves the problem when I tap a non segueing button.

```
-(IBAction) tapRecord:(id)sender
{
    [self.audioPlayer stopAudio];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The error I get is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS".  I believe its my action on the `UIAlertView` thats causing the problem.  How can I get the `UIAlertView` to appear before segueing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post any code for your `UIAlertView`, but I'm assuming that you set your alert's `delegate` to the view controller that you're segueing from. If you show an alert from a view controller that's about to be deallocated and then click a button on the alert, it will try to call the alert's `delegate` method(s) in the `delegate` view controller.

If this is what you did, you can fix it in one of two ways:

1. Set the alert's `delegate` to `nil` so it doesn't try to call any methods when a button is tapped
2. Show the alert from a view controller that isn't being deallocated

Comment: You're right.  The alert view delegate was set to self.  Setting it to nil works perfectly.  Thank you!